# Keycloak Upgrade "Failed to find provider jpa for userSessionPersister"

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, keycloak

I'm trying to upgrade my Keycloak instance, currently running Keycloak 18, to Keycloak 21.
But I always execute the database migration command from the documentation or try to execute a build, I get the following error:

```bash
sudo -u keycloak /opt/keycloak_21/bin/kc.sh --config-file=/opt/keycloak_21/conf/keycloak.conf --verbose start --spi-connections-jpa-legacy-migration-strategy=update --db=mssql --transaction-xa-enabled=false

Changes detected in configuration. Updating the server image.
Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
2023-03-09 15:29:00,793 INFO  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (main) Preview features enabled: admin-fine-grained-authz, client-secret-rotation, declarative-user-profile, openshift-integration, recovery-codes, scripts, token-exchange, update-email
2023-03-09 15:29:00,793 WARN  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (main) Experimental features enabled: dynamic-scopes, map-storage
2023-03-09 15:29:00,828 INFO  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (main) Preview features enabled: admin-fine-grained-authz, client-secret-rotation, declarative-user-profile, openshift-integration, recovery-codes, scripts, token-exchange, update-email
2023-03-09 15:29:00,828 WARN  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (main) Experimental features enabled: dynamic-scopes, map-storage
2023-03-09 15:29:01,841 INFO  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (build-57) Preview features enabled: admin-fine-grained-authz, client-secret-rotation, declarative-user-profile, openshift-integration, recovery-codes, scripts, token-exchange, update-email
2023-03-09 15:29:01,870 WARN  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (build-57) Experimental features enabled: dynamic-scopes, map-storage
2023-03-09 15:29:01,828 INFO  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (build-79) Preview features enabled: admin-fine-grained-authz, client-secret-rotation, declarative-user-profile, openshift-integration, recovery-codes, scripts, token-exchange, update-email
2023-03-09 15:29:01,874 WARN  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (build-79) Experimental features enabled: dynamic-scopes, map-storage
ERROR: Failed to run 'build' command.
Error details:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doReaugment(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:84)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:48)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:32)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.command.Build.run(Build.java:71)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1939)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2358)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2352)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2314)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2316)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.Picocli.runReAugmentation(Picocli.java:183)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.Picocli.runReAugmentationIfNeeded(Picocli.java:120)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.Picocli.parseAndRun(Picocli.java:88)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.KeycloakMain.main(KeycloakMain.java:88)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:61)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step org.keycloak.quarkus.deployment.KeycloakProcessor#configureKeycloakSessionFactory threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find provider jpa for userSessionPersister
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.deployment.KeycloakProcessor.checkProviders(KeycloakProcessor.java:799)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.deployment.KeycloakProcessor.configureKeycloakSessionFactory(KeycloakProcessor.java:366)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:335)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createProductionApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:175)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.mutability.ReaugmentTask.main(ReaugmentTask.java:69)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step org.keycloak.quarkus.deployment.KeycloakProcessor#configureKeycloakSessionFactory threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find provider jpa for userSessionPersister
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.deployment.KeycloakProcessor.checkProviders(KeycloakProcessor.java:799)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.deployment.KeycloakProcessor.configureKeycloakSessionFactory(KeycloakProcessor.java:366)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

        at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:123)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:160)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:331)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find provider jpa for userSessionPersister
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.deployment.KeycloakProcessor.checkProviders(KeycloakProcessor.java:799)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.deployment.KeycloakProcessor.configureKeycloakSessionFactory(KeycloakProcessor.java:366)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

The same behavior is when I'm attempting to upgrade to Keycloak 20 or 19.
Sadly, I don't know a lot about Java or the exceptions I get, so I hope anyone could help me or give me a hint. Every time I attempt to use Google, I get the same results, which are not mentioning the provider mentioned in my error message.

My config:

```
# Basic settings for running in production. Change accordingly before deploying the server.

# Features

features=authorization,account2,account-api,admin-fine-grained-authz,admin2,impersonation,scripts,token-exchange,web-authn,client-policies,ciba,map-storage,par,declarative-user-profile,dynamic-scopes,client-secret-rotation,step-up-authentication,recovery-codes,update-email,preview

# Database

# The database vendor.
db=mssql

# The username of the database user.
db-username=keycloak_user

# The password of the database user.
db-password=****

# The full database JDBC URL. If not provided, a default URL is set based on the selected database vendor.
db-url=jdbc:sqlserver://srv-sql.hostname.local:1433;DatabaseName=keycloak_qs;

transaction-xa-enabled=false

# Observability

# If the server should expose healthcheck endpoints.
health-enabled=true

# If the server should expose metrics endpoints.
metrics-enabled=true

# HTTP

http-enabled=true

http-host=10.*.*.***

http-port=8080

# The proxy address forwarding mode if the server is behind a reverse proxy.
proxy=edge
hostname-strict=true

hostname=kc-qs.hostname.local
hostname-strict-https=true

# Do not attach route to cookies and rely on the session affinity capabilities from reverse proxy
spi-sticky-session-encoder-infinispan-should-attach-route=false


# Health

health-enabled=true

# Logging

log=console,file

log-console-color=true

log-level=info

# Cache

cache=ispn

cache-stack=udp
```

Maybe I only need a quick prod to find the solution or to see the obvious hint in the error message.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read through the documentation about how to upgrade Keycloak? https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/#intro

I had a similar issue when upgrading, but used a custom jpa class instead of a config file so I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. Yes i followed the upgrade guide from their docs and i don't have installed custom providers.